# Laravel - Session store not set on request

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies

I recently created a new Laravel project and was following along with the guide on Authentication. When I visit either my login or register route, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in Request.php line 775:
Session store not set on request. (View: C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\test\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)
```

I haven't edited any core Laravel files, I've only created the views and added the routes to my routes.php file

```
// Authentication routes
Route::get('auth/login', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin', 'as' => 'login']);
Route::post('auth/login', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin', 'as' => 'login']);
Route::get('auth/logout', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout', 'as' => 'logout']);

// Registration routes
Route::get('auth/register', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister', 'as' => 'register']);
Route::post('auth/register', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister', 'as' => 'login']);
```

I don't have much experience with Laravel, so please excuse my ignorance. I'm aware that there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517763/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request) asking this same thing, but neither of the answers seems to work for me. Thanks for reading!

**Edit:**

Here's my register.blade.php as requested.

```
@extends('partials.main')

@section('title', 'Test | Register')

@section('content')
    <form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <div class="ui input">
          <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="ui input">
          <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="ui input">
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="ui input">
          <input type="password" name="password_confirmation"placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="ui primary button" type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: you can also replace the above routes.php with just `Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);`

Comment: and you have routes with the same name, it's wrong, they should have different names

Comment: How is your session driver configuration set?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You'll need to use the **web middleware** if you need session state, CSRF protection, and more.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```

Comment: I actually do have that, I was just including the relevant routes.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, I moved the routes inside and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mattrick : hi metrix getting same error .can you explain where you moved routes inside middleware but it showing error "No supported encrypter found. The cipher".

Comment: @ErVipinSingh you ll need to set a 32 character key in your app config. Or use `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: worked for me , if you use old() method , you have to do that .

Comment: Yes, take a look in `Kernel.php` at the `middlewareGroups` array. =)

Comment: How come they forgot to mention that in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session ?

Comment: I had and issue with laravel not persisting authentication. This fixed it as it was obvious cookies were not being created.

Comment: What if your login route is in the API?

Answer (score 91):

If adding your `routes` inside the `web middleware` doesn't work for any reason then try adding this to `$middleware` into `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
        //...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

Comment: Damn, this has worked for me, but I'm not happy that it's a "fix", not a solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using a react frontend so the route group doesn't work as I'm using react router for routes.

Comment: Holy, this is really working. thanks

Comment: this is wrong!!! if you add this for every request then your session regeneration and login might not work!!!

Comment: @AmirHassanAzimi What version of Laravel are you using? This has been tested for Laravel 5. If you are using a different version, you might see a different behavior!

Answer (score 74):

In my case (using Laravel 5.3) adding only the following 2 middleware allowed me to access session data in my API routes:

- `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class`
- `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`

Whole declaration (`$middlewareGroups` in Kernel.php):

```
'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
```

Comment: This is the right way for using session in api routes. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 31):

If Cas Bloem's answer does not apply (i.e. you've definitely got the `web` middleware on the applicable route), you might want to check the order of middlewares in your HTTP Kernel.

The default order in `Kernel.php` is this:

```
$middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];
```

Note that `VerifyCsrfToken` comes after `StartSession`. If you've got these in a different order, the dependency between them can also lead to the `Session store not set on request.` exception.

Comment: i have it exactly like that. í still get the message. I also tried putting StartSession and ShareErrorsFromSession in the $middleware array. Storate/frameword is also writeable.  (I'm using Wampserver 3 btw.)

Comment: use  'middleware' => ['web','youanother.log'],

Comment: Yep!  I was dumb and thought I'd reorder those alphabetically (because OCD) and that broke the app.  Unfortunately, I didn't test until the next day, which is why I ended up here.  Just for the record, the default order for the "web" middleware group in 5.3 is: EncryptCookies, AddQueuedCookiesToResponse, StartSession, ShareErrorsFromSession, SubstituteBindings, VerifyCsrfToken.

Answer (score 25):

A problem can be that you try to **access you session inside of your controller's  `__constructor()` function.**

From Laravel 5.3+ this is not possible anymore because it is not intended to work anyway, [as stated in the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0).

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or
>   the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was
>   never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel
>   5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

For more background information also read [Taylor](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15072#issuecomment-242769373) his response.

**Workaround**

If you still want to use this, you can dynamically create a middleware and run it in the constructor, as described in the upgrade guide:

> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly
>   in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure
>   that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use App\User;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
> use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
>
> class ProjectController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * All of the current user's projects.
>      */
>     protected $projects;
>
>     /**
>      * Create a new controller instance.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
>             $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;
>
>             return $next($request);
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This was my issue, I was trying to access a session variable inside the __constructor() method.

Answer (score 19):

**Laravel [5.4]**

My solution was to use global session helper:
***session()***

Its functionality is a little bit harder than ***$request->session()***.

**writing**:

```
session(['key'=>'value']);
```

**pushing**:

```
session()->push('key', $notification);
```

**retrieving**:

```
session('key');
```

Comment: This is not working when we write session variable in a controller and uses in another controller :(

Comment: This also worked for me. I had layers of issues. I "fixed" the problem with the Kernel suggestion, only to later discover I broke sessions by adding  StartSession to the wrong Middleware in Kernel.php — once I removed that, I ultimately found $request->session() was problematic in my custom middleware class and it fixed the issue when I switched to session() only.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using Laravel 7.x and this problem arose.. the following fixed it:

go to `kernel.php` and add these 2 classes to `protected $middleware`

```php
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

Comment: this has worked for me in the latest laravel 9 as of June 2022

Comment: But why? It should not require that. Is anyone able to explain it?

Comment: Well, this is in fact an anti-pattern for an API. The main idea of using JWT is to have a Sessionless Authentication. By doing this you will be creating a session for your user

Comment: This saved my bacon, I was building a unit test with a route that had no middleware group, didn't occur to me that I'd have to manually add StartSession to it to unit test sessions. Thanks!

Comment: @Luciano That is true but this is intended for SPA with a Laravel backend. It's fighting the tooling doing it any other way and recommended within the docs.

Comment: Assuming you're using Sanctum, I believe `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` is a better choice here as it'll start the session plus accommodate potential changes down the line

Answer (score 10):

In my case I added the following 4 lines to $middlewareGroups (in app/Http/Kernel.php):

```
'api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

**IMPORTANT: The 4 new lines must be added BEFORE 'throttle' and 'bindings'!**

Otherwise a "CSRF token not match" error will rise. I've struggled in this for several hours just to find the order is important.

This allowed me to access session in my API. I also added VerifyCsrfToken as when cookies/sessions are involved, CSRF needs to be taken care of.

Comment: If you are writing apis with laravel this is the answer your looking for :) or add [->stateless()->redirect()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite#stateless-authentication)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error with Laravel Sanctum. I fixed it by adding `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to the `api` middleware group in Kernel.php, but I later figured out this "worked" because my authentication routes were added in `api.php` instead of `web.php`, so Laravel was using the wrong auth guard.

I moved these routes here into `web.php` and then they started working properly with the `AuthenticatesUsers.php` trait:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest', 'throttle:10,5']], function () {
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('register');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');

    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

    Route::post('email/verify/{user}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
    Route::post('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend');

    Route::post('oauth/{driver}', 'Auth\OAuthController@redirectToProvider')->name('oauth.redirect');
    Route::get('oauth/{driver}/callback', 'Auth\OAuthController@handleProviderCallback')->name('oauth.callback');
});

Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

I figured out the problem after I got another weird error about `RequestGuard::logout()` does not exist.

It made me realize that my custom auth routes are calling methods from the AuthenticatesUsers trait, but I wasn't using `Auth::routes()` to accomplish it. Then I realized Laravel uses the web guard by default and that means routes should be in `routes/web.php`.

This is what my settings look like now with Sanctum and a decoupled Vue SPA app:

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

> **Note:** With Laravel Sanctum and same-domain Vue SPA, you use httpOnly cookies for session cookie, and remember me cookie, and unsecure cookie for CSRF, so you use the `web` guard for auth, and every other protected, JSON-returning route should use `auth:sanctum` middleware.

**config/auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

...

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Then you can have unit tests such as this, where critically, `Auth::check()`, `Auth::user()`, and `Auth::logout()` work as expected with minimal config and maximal usage of `AuthenticatesUsers` and `RegistersUsers` traits.

Here are a couple of my login unit tests:

**TestCase.php**

```
/**
 * Creates and/or returns the designated regular user for unit testing
 *
 * @return \App\User
 */
public function user() : User
{
    $user = User::query()->firstWhere('email', 'test-user@example.com');

    if ($user) {
        return $user;
    }

    // User::generate() is just a wrapper around User::create()
    $user = User::generate('Test User', 'test-user@example.com', self::AUTH_PASSWORD);

    return $user;
}

/**
 * Resets AuthManager state by logging out the user from all auth guards.
 * This is used between unit tests to wipe cached auth state.
 *
 * @param array $guards
 * @return void
 */
protected function resetAuth(array $guards = null) : void
{
    $guards = $guards ?: array_keys(config('auth.guards'));

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        $guard = $this->app['auth']->guard($guard);

        if ($guard instanceof SessionGuard) {
            $guard->logout();
        }
    }

    $protectedProperty = new \ReflectionProperty($this->app['auth'], 'guards');
    $protectedProperty->setAccessible(true);
    $protectedProperty->setValue($this->app['auth'], []);
}
```

**LoginTest.php**

```
protected $auth_guard = 'web';

/** @test */
public function it_can_login()
{
    $user = $this->user();

    $this->postJson(route('login'), ['email' => $user->email, 'password' => TestCase::AUTH_PASSWORD])
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'user' => [
                ...expectedUserFields,
            ],
        ]);

    $this->assertEquals(Auth::check(), true);
    $this->assertEquals(Auth::user()->email, $user->email);
    $this->assertAuthenticated($this->auth_guard);
    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user, $this->auth_guard);

    $this->resetAuth();
}

/** @test */
public function it_can_logout()
{
    $this->actingAs($this->user())
        ->postJson(route('logout'))
        ->assertStatus(204);

    $this->assertGuest($this->auth_guard);

    $this->resetAuth();
}
```

I overrided the `registered` and `authenticated` methods in the Laravel auth traits so that they return the user object instead of just the 204 OPTIONS:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}

protected function registered(Request $request, User $user)
{
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

Look at the vendor code for the auth traits. You can use them untouched, plus those two above methods.

- vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RegistersUsers.php
- vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php

Here is my Vue SPA's Vuex actions for login:

```
async login({ commit }, credentials) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(route('login'), {
            ...credentials,
            remember: credentials.remember || undefined,
        });

        commit(FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, { user: data.user });
        commit(LOGIN);

        return commit(CLEAR_INTENDED_URL);
    } catch (err) {
        commit(LOGOUT);
        throw new Error(`auth/login# Problem logging user in: ${err}.`);
    }
},

async logout({ commit }) {
    try {
        await axios.post(route('logout'));

        return commit(LOGOUT);
    } catch (err) {
        commit(LOGOUT);

        throw new Error(`auth/logout# Problem logging user out: ${err}.`);
    }
},
```

It took me over a week to get Laravel Sanctum + same-domain Vue SPA + auth unit tests all working up to my standard, so hopefully my answer here can help save others time in the future.

Comment: Do i need to use login if I want user's authenticated? I do not have login since jwt is authenticated via proxy. I just want to set session value to authenticated so that subsequent requests do not need to auth with 3rd party again. Getting " Session store not set on request."..

Comment: If you make a question and link it here, it will create a nice follow-reference for someone else, and I might be able to help; but it's been a while since I was looking at auth code. `Session store not set on request` might relate directly to `StartSession::class`. Something upstream of that might not be getting set properly, or your usage of `web` and/or `api` isn't aligned properly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error but it was due to a misconfiguration in my sanctum.php file. Inside the block for the stateful Domains, I had still a development domain instead of my production domain.

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'mydomain.com')
),
```

It throwed the exact same error.

Hope that helps someone. 
Cheers

Comment: This was my issue - a note to future viewers and future me: you can set wildcards in `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` such as `*.myproject.test`

Answer (score 4):

Are you facing this issue when running a test for SPA authentication with sanctum?

### Solution:

Add this line to `tests/TestCase.php`:

```php
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->withHeader('origin', config('app.url'));
    }
```

### Explanation:

In order to use sanctum for SPA auth, you have to add this to api middleware:

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class
```

`EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` class only works when its static method `fromFrontend` returns true:

```php
 public static function fromFrontend($request)
    {
        $domain = $request->headers->get('referer') ?: $request->headers->get('origin');

        if (is_null($domain)) {
            return false;
        }
        // ... ommited
}
```

Session store is not set because `$domain` is null when this method is running on unit tests.

Comment: this worked for me. I'm using `sanctum` and `auth` routes are inside the `api.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

Do you can use `->stateless()` before the `->redirect()`.
Then you dont need the session anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is what you are facing: You are calling a request association session which is not instantiated to the request you made. You only need to setLaravelSession on the request which will init session on request on which you want to have the session data available.

```
$request->setLaravelSession(session())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue testing with postman.

The thing i was missing were "referer" header. The domain there should be matching one of sanctrum domains, so the request be concidered as stateful

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSRF enter `'before'=>'csrf'`

In your case
`Route::get('auth/login', ['before'=>'csrf','uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin', 'as' => 'login']);`

For more details view Laravel 5 Documentation [Security Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes)

Answer (score 0):

It's not on the laravel documentation, I have been an hour to achieve this:

My session didn't persist until i used the "save" method...

```
$request->session()->put('lang','en_EN');
$request->session()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the domain address of your spa to your config/sanctum.php file at the 'stateful' section

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel with Passport API ( Middleware => auth:api)

Remove: 
`\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,`

in the $middleware array from Kernel.php

Answer (score -1):

in my case it was just to put 
return ; 
at the end of function where  i have set session

Answer (score -1):

Laravel 5.3+  web middleware group is automatically applied to your routes/web.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

Unless you modify kernel $middlewareGroups array in an unsupported order, probably you are trying to inject requests as a regular dependency from the constructor.

Use request as

```
public function show(Request $request){

}
```

instead of

```
public function __construct(Request $request){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my own case (in Laravel 5.8) the `session.php` config file in my Laravel project located in the `../[mylaravelapp]/config/` directory was missing. Hence, I copied the missing file from another Laravel project back to the `config` directory, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

just add in top **public/index.php**

```
ob_start();
```

it's work with shared host

---

if not work try change this code in **app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php**

```
protected $proxies;
```

to

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

Answer (score -1):

The following are working for me...

Making session when user is logging in

```
$r->session()->put('usrSession',$r->uName);
```

Here 'usrSession' is my key and 'uName' is coming from request's variable (actually its the unique username of that user)

Flushing (all) sessions when user is logging out

```
$r->session()->flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

Some note could help you as helped me:

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67922485/2144566) says, `dd('')` function has some conflicts with `session` feature (and of course maybe with some other features like cookies, ... I didn't test);

The resone is unknown for me! maybe `dd()` clears buffer.

So just **DON'T** use `dd()` in combination with `session`.