# Session return null anyway

Tags: laravel, session, service, null

My project is using three different services and now I never can get sessions values, I've tried the laravel site tutorial and fallowing link question :
[Laravel - Session returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233343/laravel-session-returns-null)

But none of them worked!

In the first, i used  this library:

```
use Session;
```

In a controller `class` :

```
$result = SocketHelper::sendRequest($req);

Session::put('uuid', $result->uuid);
Session::save();

Session::put('userId', $result->userID);

return Redirect::route('login_step_two');
```

In an other method :

```
$uuid = Session::get('uuid');

$userId = Session::get('userId');
```

But these are `null`! does I have to use cookie?
I recently upgrade to *laravel 5.4*

Please help me! It's made me confused!

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, what version have you upgraded from? Also, where are you trying to access the session e.g. in the routes file, in a controller method, in the `__construct` method in a controller?

Comment: it was 5.2 and i first upgraded to 5.3 then 5.4, and now I'm using session in controllers, three of methodes, I mean it's needed to put session in auth method and get in tow other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the null result was becouse I was posting the value of $request to an other template and it was changed it the way :))) !
so easy to know !

Answer (score 2):

Try saving `Session` explicitly like this, give it a try it worked for me, hope same for you.

```
Session::put('test_session', 'test message');
Session::save();
```

And retrieve it like this

```
echo Session::get('test_session');
```

And forget it like this:

```
Session::forget('test_session');
Session::save();
```

Comment: I tested it, I wasn't using this code: Session::save(); but it's not working yet

Comment: @Gaurav Rai thank you. this method worked for me on laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly upgraded to laravel 5.4?

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)
Sessions

**Symfony Compatibility**

Laravel's session handlers no longer implements Symfony's `SessionInterface`. Implementing this interface required us to implement extraneous features that were not needed by the framework. Instead, a new `Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session` interface has been defined and may be used instead. The following code changes should also be applied:

All calls to the ->set() method should be changed to `->put()`. Typically, Laravel applications would never call the set method since it has never been documented within the Laravel documentation. However, it is included here out of caution.

All calls to the `->getToken()` method should be changed to `->token()`.

All calls to the `$request->setSession()` method should be changed to `setLaravelSession()`.

Comment: here is part of my codes:
Session::put('uuid', $result->uuid); //to set session
$uuid = Session::get('uuid');// to get session in an other method of the controller class but i recieve null
I didn't understand the first part of ur answer , do i need to implement Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session interface now? and isn't it implemented on new frameworks? where should i do that? which class/path?

Comment: do u have any idea?

Comment: IF you were using `SessionInterface` then yes you have to change it and use 'Session' now

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the rights to write session files in php session directory ?
Check the path returned by `session_save_path()` and check if your php user has the rights to write in it, check also if there is files in the directory and what are their creation date.

Comment: thx for ur answer, i used this method and saw the path was: C:\xampp\tmp while framework/session is given in config/session and a new file is added to this path!

Comment: Ok I guessed you were in Linux environment, but if you are on Windows and Session seems to work, it's probably a problem with the framework. Check other answers.