# Session store not set on request in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My website got an error like this:

[image]

I also tried some solution like wrap Route in middleware web it it didn't works

Here is my Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\Activated;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \anlutro\LaravelSettings\SaveMiddleware::class,
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            Activated::class
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
(The rest of file)
    }
```

How can i resolve that :((

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the web middleware if you need session state, CSRF protection, and more.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```

your kernel.php should look like this

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \anlutro\LaravelSettings\SaveMiddleware::class,
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            Activated::class
        ],
```

Comment: I also tried this but it didn't works

Comment: The same thing :((, I also run php artisan opt to clear the cache

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload and then check

Comment: OMG !! it's really works :D, charming !!!

Comment: great bro :) glad could help you

Answer (score 1):

If adding your **routes** inside the **web middleware** doesn't work for any reason then try adding this to **$middleware** into **Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    //...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to create a Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware AnyNameYouWant
```

it will create a nice boilerplate for you.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   // Your Logic
}

  return redirect('whereever you want to redirect');
}
```

Then include it in your middleware

```
   'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,

      \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \anlutro\LaravelSettings\SaveMiddleware::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class
    ],
```

I hope this helps