# Sharing a variable in controller - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the user_id from the session and using it quite a bit throughout my contrpller. So am looking at ways of retrieving that variable.

I have set everything up to get it (How I understand) but the Variable is returning

> null

My Controller looks as follows :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\VideoLog;

class VideoController extends Controller
{
    private $user_id;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = session('id');
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    public function log_watched(Request $request)
    {
        dd($this->user_id);

        // See If Video Has Been Watched Before....
        $video_watched = VideoLog::where('user_id', $this->user_id);
    }
}
```

Is it something to do with the session?

How would I retrieve it?

Comment: I have something to optimise your code `$this->user_id = session('id');` you don't need  `$user_id = session('id');` and for question, I think your session is `null` because is not set at all

Comment: Thanks for optimising. I can confirm that id is set elsewhere. I can get it through $request->session()->get('id');

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Latest version - 5.4

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it be `$this->user_id = $request->session()->get('id');`

Comment: @WillParky93 Can you use Request in the __construct method?

Comment: @StuBlackett you are passing the `Request $request` in `__construct` so yes

Comment: That seems to be returning an error... "Session store not set on request."

Comment: Ah, I'm not a user of laravel framework but it does appear you cannot use `session` in `__construct`, maybe [this may be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because the controller `__construct` method is run before the middleware that starts the session.

([more information here](https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3))

As the post says, you can get round this issue by using the `middleware` method in the controller's `__construct` method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $this->user_id = session('id');

        return $next($request);
    });

}
```

This will allow you to set the `user_id` on the controller.

Comment: Thank you Ross! Works a treat

Comment: @StuBlackett Glad I could help :)