# Why do I get two different results when calling Session::get('locale') from distinct classes in laravel 5.5 app?

Tags: php, session, request, session-variables, laravel-5.5

I recently found [this](https://github.com/stevebauman/translation) laravel package on github and after installing it, I noticed that the **setLocale()** function in Translation.php class didn't work as expected. Many issues have been opened about this bug and I started trying to fix it as the maintainer's time was limited due to other open source projects : [(Adldap2/Adldap2](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2) and [Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel) as stated [here](https://github.com/stevebauman/translation/issues/27).

In Translation.php class, I first changed **getLocale()** function from

```html
    public function getLocale()
    {
        
        if ($this->request->hasCookie('locale')) {
            return $this->request->cookie('locale');
        } else {
            return $this->getConfigDefaultLocale();
        }
        
     }
```

to

```html
public function getLocale()
 {

    if ($this->request->session()->has('locale')) {
        return $this->request->session()->get('locale');
    } else {
        return $this->getConfigDefaultLocale();
    }
    
  }
```

because  the comments in the Translation contract specified that sessions were to be used for the **getLocale()** function.

Then, after inserting some text to translate with the provided helper function {{_t('text')}} in my blade templates, I dumped the result in my localization middleware to see if everything was fine with **dd(Translate::getLocale)**.

I got a 'Session store not set on request.' error. After some googling, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request) on Stack Overflow and decided to use the helper function session() and later the Session facade as I found it more convenient.

After these operations, **dd(Translate::getLocale)** worked fine and I proceeded to modify **setLocale()** function from

```html
    public function setLocale($code = '')
    {
        $this->locale = $code;
    }
```

to

```html
    public function setLocale($code = '')
    {
        $this->locale = $code;
        $this->request->session()->put('locale', $locale);
    }
```

and lastly

```html
    public function setLocale($code = '')
    {
        $this->locale = $code;
        session(['locale' => $this->locale]);
    }
```

in order to avoid the 'Session store not set on request' error.

Everything worked correctly.

Despite these actions, the translation still didn't work as expected.

Then, I dumped **Translation::getLocale()** first in my localization middleware and then in my Translation.php class and I got two different results : 'en'  for the Translation.php class and 'fr'(Automatically detected by the middleware).

I also added automatic locale detection to the Translation following this [code snippet](https://github.com/spiritix/translation/blob/master/src/Translation.php#L86) and tried again with no success.

Finally, I dumped the session variable with **dd(Session::all)** in the two files and got this from Translation.php class :

```js
array:4 [▼
  "locale" => "en"
  "_token" => "3FYWDEaPk47ZcqIS2u5KzGmwz7vI0x3G8h9GkNZP"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

and that from localization middleware :

```js
array:4 [▼
  "locale" => "fr"
]
```

After checking my database where my sessions are stored, I found only one session, so I don't understand why this is happening.

I also checked some blog posts about laravel service container as **$app->make()** have been used in Translation class constructor, but I'm stuck.

Here are my current Translation.php and localization middleware :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Session;
use App;
use Config;
use Translation;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

  
        if ( Session::has('locale')) {
            $locale = Session::get('locale', Config::get('app.locale'));
        } else {
            $locale = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);
   /*$this->config->get('translation.locales')*/
            if ($locale != 'fr' && $locale != 'en') {
                $locale = 'en';
            }
   
   Session::put('locale', $locale);
        }
  
  
        App::setLocale($locale);
  
 //dd(Session::get('locale'));
  
  
  Translation::setLocale($locale);

  
  
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

namespace Stevebauman\Translation;

use ErrorException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Stevebauman\Translation\Contracts\Client as ClientInterface;
use Stevebauman\Translation\Contracts\Translation as TranslationInterface;
use UnexpectedValueException;

//use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Translation implements TranslationInterface
{
 /**
     * Holds the application .
     *
     * @var object
     */
    protected $app ;
 
    /**
     * Holds the application locale.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $locale = '';

    /**
     * Holds the locale model.
     *
     * @var Model
     */
    protected $localeModel;

    /**
     * Holds the translation model.
     *
     * @var Model
     */
    protected $translationModel;

    /**
     * Holds the translation client.
     *
     * @var ClientInterface
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * Holds the current cache instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager
     */
    protected $cache;

    /**
     * Holds the current config instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Config\Repository
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * Holds the current request instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * The default amount of time (minutes) to store the cached translations.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $cacheTime = 30;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
  $this->app = $app;
  
        $this->config = $this->app->make('config');
        $this->cache = $this->app->make('cache');
        $this->request = $this->app->make('request');

        $this->localeModel = $this->app->make($this->getConfigLocaleModel());
        $this->translationModel = $this->app->make($this->getConfigTranslationModel());
        $this->client = $this->app->make($this->getConfigClient());
  
        // Set the default locale to the current application locale
        $this->setLocale($this->getConfigDefaultLocale());

        // Set the cache time from the configuration
        $this->setCacheTime($this->getConfigCacheTime());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function translate($text = '', $replacements = [], $toLocale = '', $runOnce = false)
    {
        try {
            // Make sure $text is actually a string and not and object / int
            $this->validateText($text);

            // Get the default translation text. This will insert the translation
            // and the default application locale if they don't
            // exist using firstOrCreate
            $defaultTranslation = $this->getDefaultTranslation($text);

            // If there are replacements inside the array we need to convert them
            // into google translate safe placeholders. ex :name to __name__
            if (count($replacements) > 0) {
                $defaultTranslation->translation = $this->makeTranslationSafePlaceholders($text, $replacements);
            }
   
   if ( Session::has('locale')) {
            $locale = Session::get('locale');
        } else {
            $locale = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);
   /*$this->config->get('translation.locales')*/
            if ($locale != 'fr' && $locale != 'en') {
                $locale = 'en';
            }
   
   Session::put('locale', $locale);
        }
  
  
        App::setLocale($locale);
  
  //dd($locale);
  
  Translation::setLocale($locale);

            // If a toLocale has been provided, we're only translating a single string, so
            // we won't call the getLocale method as it retrieves and sets the default
            // session locale. If it has not been provided, we'll get the
            // default locale, and set it on the current session.
            if ($toLocale) {
                $toLocale = $this->firstOrCreateLocale($toLocale);
            } else {
    //dd(Session::all());
                $toLocale = $this->firstOrCreateLocale($this->getLocale());
            }

            // Check if translation is requested for default locale.
            // If it is default locale we can just return default translation.
            if ($defaultTranslation->getAttribute($this->localeModel->getForeignKey()) == $toLocale->getKey()) {
                return $this->makeReplacements($defaultTranslation->translation, $replacements);
            }

            // Since we are not on default translation locale, we will have to
            // create (or get first) translation for provided locale where
            // parent translation is our default translation.
            $translation = $this->firstOrCreateTranslation(
                $toLocale,
                $defaultTranslation->translation,
                $defaultTranslation
            );

   //dd($this->makeReplacements($translation->translation, $replacements));
            return $this->makeReplacements($translation->translation, $replacements);
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            // If foreign key integrity constrains fail, we have a caching issue
            if (!$runOnce) {
                // If this has not been run before, proceed

                // Burst locale cache
                $this->removeCacheLocale($toLocale->code);

                // Burst translation cache
                $this->removeCacheTranslation($this->translationModel->firstOrNew([
                        $toLocale->getForeignKey() => $toLocale->getKey(),
                        'translation'              => $text,
                    ])
                );

                // Attempt translation 1 more time
                return $this->translate($text, $replacements, $toLocale->code, $runOnce = true);
            } else {
                // If it has already tried translating once and failed again,
                // prevent infinite loops and just return the text
                return $text;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAppLocale()
    {
        return $this->config->get('app.locale');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRoutePrefix()
    {
        $locale = $this->request->segment($this->getConfigRequestSegment());

        $locales = $this->getConfigLocales();

        if (is_array($locales) && in_array($locale, array_keys($locales))) {
            return $locale;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
  
  //dd($this->request->session()->has('locale'));
        /*if ($this->request->session()->has('locale')) {
            return $this->request->session()->get('locale');
        } else {
            return $this->getConfigDefaultLocale();
        }*/
  
  /*if (session('locale')) {
            return session('locale');
        } else {
            return $this->getConfigDefaultLocale();
        }*/
  
  return Session::get('locale'); //$this->locale;
  
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setLocale($code = '')
    {
        $this->locale = $code;
  /*if(in_array($code, $this->config->get('translation.locales'))){*/
  //$this->request->session()->put('locale', $locale);
  session(['locale' => $this->locale]);
  /* } else {} */
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDefaultTranslation($text)
    {
        $locale = $this->firstOrCreateLocale($this->getConfigDefaultLocale());

        return $this->firstOrCreateTranslation($locale, $text);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces laravel translation placeholders with google
     * translate safe placeholders. Ex:.
     *
     * Converts:
     *      :name
     *
     * Into:
     *      __name__
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @param array  $replace
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function makeTranslationSafePlaceholders($text, array $replace = [])
    {
        if (count($replace) > 0) {
            foreach ($replace as $key => $value) {
                // Search for :key
                $search = ':'.$key;

                // Replace it with __key__
                $replace = $this->makeTranslationSafePlaceholder($key);

                // Perform the replacements
                $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
            }
        }

        return $text;
    }

    /**
     * Makes a placeholder by the specified key.
     *
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function makeTranslationSafePlaceholder($key = '')
    {
        return '___'.strtolower($key).'___';
    }

    /**
     * Make the place-holder replacements on the specified text.
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @param array  $replacements
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function makeReplacements($text, array $replacements)
    {
        if (count($replacements) > 0) {
            foreach ($replacements as $key => $value) {
                $replace = $this->makeTranslationSafePlaceholder($key);

                $text = str_ireplace($replace, $value, $text);
            }
        }

        return $text;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves or creates a locale from the specified code.
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return Model
     */
    protected function firstOrCreateLocale($code)
    {
        $cachedLocale = $this->getCacheLocale($code);

        if ($cachedLocale) {
            return $cachedLocale;
        }

        $name = $this->getConfigLocaleByCode($code);

        $locale = $this->localeModel->firstOrCreate([
            'code' => $code,
            'name' => $name,
        ]);

        $this->setCacheLocale($locale);

        return $locale;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a translation.
     *
     * @param Model  $locale
     * @param string $text
     * @param Model  $parentTranslation
     *
     * @return Model
     */
    protected function firstOrCreateTranslation(Model $locale, $text, $parentTranslation = null)
    {
        // We'll check to see if there's a cached translation
        // first before we try and hit the database.
        $cachedTranslation = $this->getCacheTranslation($locale, $text);

        if ($cachedTranslation instanceof Model) {
            return $cachedTranslation;
        }

        // Check if auto translation is enabled. If so we'll run
        // the text through google translate and
        // save it, then cache it.
        if ($parentTranslation && $this->autoTranslateEnabled()) {
            $this->client->setSource($parentTranslation->locale->code);
            $this->client->setTarget($locale->code);

            try {
                $text = $this->client->translate($text);
            } catch (ErrorException $e) {
                // Request to translate failed, set the text
                // to the parent translation.
                $text = $parentTranslation->translation;
            } catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
                // Looks like something other than text was passed in,
                // we'll set the text to the parent translation
                // for this exception as well.
                $text = $parentTranslation->translation;
            }
        }

        if ($parentTranslation) {
            // If a parent translation is given we're looking for it's child translation.
            $translation = $this->translationModel->firstOrNew([
                $locale->getForeignKey()                 => $locale->getKey(),
                $this->translationModel->getForeignKey() => $parentTranslation->getKey(),
            ]);
        } else {
            // Otherwise we're creating the parent translation.
            $translation = $this->translationModel->firstOrNew([
                $locale->getForeignKey() => $locale->getKey(),
                'translation'            => $text,
            ]);
        }

        if (empty($translation->getAttribute('translation'))) {
            // We need to make sure we don't overwrite the translation
            // if it exists already in case it was modified.
            $translation->setAttribute('translation', $text);
        }

        if ($translation->isDirty()) {
            $translation->save();
        }

        // Cache the translation so it's retrieved faster next time
        $this->setCacheTranslation($translation);

        return $translation;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a cache key to the specified locale and text.
     *
     * @param Model $translation
     */
    protected function setCacheTranslation(Model $translation)
    {
        if ($translation->parent instanceof Model) {
            $id = $this->getTranslationCacheId($translation->locale, $translation->parent->translation);
        } else {
            $id = $this->getTranslationCacheId($translation->locale, $translation->translation);
        }

        if (!$this->cache->has($id)) {
            $this->cache->put($id, $translation, $this->cacheTime);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the translation from the cache manually.
     *
     * @param Model $translation
     */
    protected function removeCacheTranslation(Model $translation)
    {
        $id = $this->getTranslationCacheId($translation->locale, $translation->translation);

        if ($this->cache->has($id)) {
            $this->cache->forget($id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the cached translation from the specified locale
     * and text.
     *
     * @param Model  $locale
     * @param string $text
     *
     * @return bool|Model
     */
    protected function getCacheTranslation(Model $locale, $text)
    {
        $id = $this->getTranslationCacheId($locale, $text);

        $cachedTranslation = $this->cache->get($id);

        if ($cachedTranslation instanceof Model) {
            return $cachedTranslation;
        }

        // Cached translation wasn't found, let's return
        // false so we know to generate one.
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a cache key to the specified locale.
     *
     * @param Model $locale
     */
    protected function setCacheLocale(Model $locale)
    {
        if (!$this->cache->has($locale->code)) {
            $id = sprintf('translation.%s', $locale->code);

            $this->cache->put($id, $locale, $this->cacheTime);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a cached locale from the specified locale code.
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function getCacheLocale($code)
    {
        $id = sprintf('translation.%s', $code);

        if ($this->cache->has($id)) {
            return $this->cache->get($id);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a locale from the cache.
     *
     * @param string $code
     */
    protected function removeCacheLocale($code)
    {
        $id = sprintf('translation.%s', $code);

        if ($this->cache->has($id)) {
            $this->cache->forget($id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a unique translation code by compressing the text
     * using a PHP compression function.
     *
     * @param Model  $locale
     * @param string $text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getTranslationCacheId(Model $locale, $text)
    {
        $compressed = $this->compressString($text);

        return sprintf('translation.%s.%s', $locale->code, $compressed);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a the english name of the locale code entered from the config file.
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getConfigLocaleByCode($code)
    {
        $locales = $this->getConfigLocales();

        if (is_array($locales) && array_key_exists($code, $locales)) {
            return $locales[$code];
        }

        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the time to store the translations and locales in cache.
     *
     * @param int $time
     */
    protected function setCacheTime($time)
    {
        if (is_numeric($time)) {
            $this->cacheTime = $time;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the default locale from the configuration.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getConfigDefaultLocale()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.default_locale', 'en');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the locale model from the configuration.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getConfigLocaleModel()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.models.locale', Models\Locale::class);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the translation model from the configuration.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getConfigTranslationModel()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.models.translation', Models\Translation::class);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the translation client from the configuration.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getConfigClient()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.clients.client', Clients\GoogleTranslate::class);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the request segment to retrieve the locale from.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getConfigRequestSegment()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.request_segment', 1);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the array of configuration locales.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getConfigLocales()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.locales');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the cache time set from the configuration file.
     *
     * @return string|int
     */
    protected function getConfigCacheTime()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.cache_time', $this->cacheTime);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the auto translate configuration option.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function autoTranslateEnabled()
    {
        return $this->config->get('translation.auto_translate', true);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the md5 hash of a string.
     *
     * Used for storing cache keys for translations.
     *
     * @param $string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compressString($string)
    {
        return md5($string);
    }

    /**
     * Validates the inserted text to make sure it's a string.
     *
     * @param $text
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function validateText($text)
    {
        if (!is_string($text)) {
            $message = 'Invalid Argument. You must supply a string to be translated.';

            throw new InvalidArgumentException($message);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you!!