# Laravel sessions not saving when called from Postman or Guzzle

Tags: laravel, session, postman, laravel-5.5, guzzle

I'm experiencing a problem with sessions in Laravel. My project consists about two projects, one an API and another a WebApp. Both with Laravel 5.5.

The problem is that I want to save a session **in my API project** but it isn't saved. I save the session like this in `api.php`:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    session(['data' => "data"]);
    session()->save();
});
```

- If I visit: http://mydomain.dev/test through Firefox, I can see the session in the Laravel DebugBar because it has been saved:

[image]

- If I make a request with Postman to that URL, session doesn't appear in the Laravel DebugBar! **It isn't saved**.

After some research, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393714/3525362) and people say to include in `Kernel.php` these two lines:

```
protected $middleware = [
        //...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

I have already added those two lines and the problem persists.

**The same happens with Guzzle**. From my WebApp, I make a GET call to my API. In the method called in the API, I save a session, and when I retrieve the session in another method of the API, I get `null` because session hasn't been saved!

My suspicion is that Postman and Guzzle problems with sessions are related, and that there's something I'm missing.

My `config\session.php` files are as default. I know I have as alternative to save sessions in database, but I would prefer   to keep it as default, but if I don't have any alternative, I will change my `SESSION_DRIVER` option from `session.php` from *file* to *database*.

Comment: APIs are and should be session less. They can not handle it. That's why token based authentications are used.

Answer (score 1):

**APIs are and should be sessionless/stateless**. 
They can not handle it.

That's why token based authentications are used. 
In order to make you sure about it. Write a `route` in `web.php` file and hit it from `postman` or `browser` then you will see a session info if any.

Comment: I know APIs should be stateless, but I need to save a session in my API project because from API, I manage PayPal payments, so when PayPal redirects back to my website after payment, I need access to the shopping cart I saved in the session.