# using GET in Laravel API routes

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to set up a Laravel API but somehow every time I try to use get I get the following error:
`Session store not set on request.`

It works when I place it out side of the (api) middleware but in that case no authentication would be needed.
With post it works perfectly but somehow when I use get I keep getting the error.

This what I have in my routes/api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
        return 'test';
    });
});
```

PHP version:  7.2.9

Laravel version: 5.6.17

Homestead version: 6.3.0

This is specificly in the auth:api middleware which makes it different from

> [Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Comment: @RonS that question is not about API routes

Comment: Your OP was not specific to POST requests.

Comment: just fully read my question and you'll see its slighty different, so instead of marking mine as a duplicate you should read again

Comment: If you could read the second comment on my answer, you would have found the solution.

Comment: my original post was specific to GET requests (and still is), I didn't change it much, your solution was basicly to set is as a non-api route

Comment: "You are not setting the MiddleWare 'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession', this could be a cause for this error" my second comment.

Comment: that answer is correct but its a different answer, I cannot mark a comment as the correct answer, there is no reason to report my post as a duplicate and downvoting me

Answer (score 0):

Use the web middleware if you need session state, CSRF protection, and more...

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```

Comment: the problem with that is that the authentication is no longer needed

Comment: You are not setting the MiddleWare 'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession', this could be a cause for this error.

Comment: to add authentication add 'auth:api' to the middleware

Comment: @PaulRoefs you stated "authentication is no longer needed".

Comment: no, I stated it wasn't needed with your code, which means you can access the page without authentication.
That's not something you'd want for an API.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to include StartSession in $middlewareGroups in my App\Kernel.php solved my problem

```
'api' => [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```