# Unable to create Request object in laravel 5.6 controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Controller name **MyController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request){
        //
        $request->session()->put('key', '123');
        $data = $request->session()->get('key');
        print_r($data);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id){
        //
    }
    public function contact(){
        return view('contact');
    }

    public function createSession(Request $request){
        //
        $request->session()->put('key', '123');
        $data = $request->session()->get('key');
        print_r($data);
    }
    public function viewSession_v1(Request $request){
        $data = $request->session()->get('key');
        print_r($data);
    }
    public function viewSession_v2(Request $request){
        $data = $request->session()->get('key');
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('createSession', 'MyController@createSession');
Route::get('viewSession-1', 'MyController@viewSession_v1');
Route::get('viewSession-2', 'MyController@viewSession_v2');
```

Now when I call `"createSession"` it will create new session and when i call either `"viewSession-1"` or `"viewSession-2"` it will display session value but I want to remove `Request $request` from `viewSession_v2()` so I did following code:

```
public function viewSession_v2(){
        $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
        $data = $request->session()->get('key');
        print_r($data);
    }
```

Now when I call `"viewSession-2"` it will give me following error 
[image: Error Snap 1]
[image: Error Snap 2]

Please anyone can tell me how can I create request object in `method/function?` and why it gives me an error here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Comment: No it's not duplicate question.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have access to the `request()` and `session()` helpers:

```
public function viewSession_v2(){
      $data = request()->session()->get('key');
      print_r($data);
}
```

or

```
public function viewSession_v2(){
      $data = session()->get('key');
      print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: It looks nice for me

Answer (score 0):

As we know Laravel provides `web middleware` concepts. I think you should use to remove the session request.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Or you can put this condition as:

```
public function viewSession_v2(Request $request){
    if($request->hasSession()) {
            $data = $request->session()->get('key');
            print_r($data);
        }
}
```

Comment: No i have to create request object here in the function. i can't do that in route.

Comment: I don't understand when i create request object as function parameter it works perfectly then why it's not working in the function body?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the `request()` helper?

Comment: Please can you explain how i use request() helper for session?

Comment: As we know that the session() is a helper that gives you a faster access to request()->session().

Comment: Or even just use the `session()` helper. I'm not going to post multi-line code as a comment, if the answer I'm about to post doesn't satisfy your question (because I'm not sure I actually know what your question is) then just comment on it and I'll delete it.

Comment: see documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session and https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request