# laravel 5: "Session store not set on request." in api.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I get user data via this link:

```
https://www.example.com/api/v1/user?api_token=e0220d90-e6e4-11a2-bddd-c6a491dff8e7mb
```

and in **api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'API\v1','middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  Route::get('/user' , 'AuthController@user');
});
```

when api_token is true, it return me user data.

but when api_token  is false, it return me an error:

> "Session store not set on request."

I try add this code in end of api.php to handle wrong api_token

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return response(['status' => 403]);
});
```

But again,I get same error

what is my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Comment: Session is not set within api routes as apis should be stateless.