# How to fix laravel session store not set on request while using Api

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

Earlier i tried this approach [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request) but it gives 419 issue on local

```
        'api' => [
            // do not resolve Session store not set on request issue register user
            // \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

So after following laravel docs. I came to know sanctum.php and figured out the exact issue. And remove those two lines from kernel.php

**Solution:**
Set **APP_URL** correctly in environment variables as being used to set stateful domains in */config/sanctum.php*. If issue is on production use production domain.

```
  'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I do have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the reason it result in 419. There are some other reason as well.