# Laravel 9 - Session store not set on request on 404 page using view composers

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm using a view composer to store global variable on all views `$currency` from sessions() for all views.

My view `Composer.php`:

```
public function __construct(
    protected Request $request,
) {}

public function compose(View $view): void
{
    $currency = $this->request->session()->get('currency', config('app.currency') );
```

app\Providers\ViewServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Facades\View::composer('*', CurrencyComposer::class);
}
```

But my problem is I'm getting the following error on the error pages **404 page**

> Session store not set on request

I have tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

```
protected $middleware = [
    //...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
 ];
```

Which does fix my issue but then I'm unable to set any sessions it will refresh all session on every page load.

Comment: Can you show your route file ? To use sessions, your route must use the web middleware.

Comment: issue is on error pages eg 404. Doesnt have a route file for.

Comment: It seems like the error is caused because the session is not available in the error pages (like 404). One possible solution to this issue is to add a middleware that ensures the session is available on these pages as well.

Comment: Yeah I have tired a if statement - if($this->request->session()) but same error. How do I add a middleware to error pages tho?

Comment: store all global variable in seesion  so we don't need to do run mysql query every time.  I thinking the same to cache somewhere and don't realize the session. Thanks for inspiration i will check  and may be help you

Comment: Can I ask if your views are inside the `views` without subfolders ? or it is inside the `subfolder` inside the `views` folder ? Like `views/pages/page.blade.php` something or `views/page.blade.php` ?

Comment: @xenooooo - So im mostly using livewire and all views are in either `views/livewire/guest` or `views/livewire/admin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a closure based composers in ViewServiceProvider. Using a if statement to check if session is set before setting the $view.

app\Providers\ViewServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
     Facades\View::composer('*', function ($view) {
          if (session()->has('currency')) {
               ...

               $view->with([
                'currency' => $currency,
               ]);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may have already found out, the session is only available when the StartSession middleware is applied to the route.

Alternatively, you can also consider using the cookie, which is available to all routes. For example, you can create a custom view for the 404 error page at resources/views/errors/404.blade.php, and read the cookie using the request() helper."

```php
<?php
$cookie = request()->cookie('xxx-you-used-for-the-currency');

echo $cookie;
```

Comment: I dont actually need the currency for the 404 error pages. I only need the currency (session) for all other pages. 

But because im using the * to load the veiw composser its also loading for the 404 page.

Comment: @TonySawlwin you can use cookie for other pages as well, if you do not need it for the 404 page

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the wildcard with the folder name :

```
Facades\View::composer('livewire/*', CurrencyComposer::class);
```

It will only share the views under the `livewire` folder inside the `views` folder. Or if you want more specific

```
Facades\View::composer(['livewire/admin/*','livewire/guest/*'], CurrencyComposer::class);
```

Comment: definetely a good solution but can still cause a issue if wanting the comproser to be available outside of livewire. ended up going to closure based composers as seemed most suited.